# how to check & force garbage collector to collect the objects of same class which is previously created..?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created C# winform application which is load controls dynamically from database specification.i am using Split container Panel.My application load two window forms in panel1 as "MenuForm" and panel2 as "canvasForm" .when i clicked in "menuForm's" menu the object of "canvasForm" is created and placed in panel2 as per click. Application running fine. but problem is that however i clicked on menu form number of canvas form's object is created and Garbage collector is not collected and memory of that project's process is increases simultaneously which i can see in "Task Manager" of windows.how to resolved this issue?.

Example : if i started application , process memory show in windows Task Manager like 17,572 K
when i clicked numbers of time in menu form for selecting menu.Task Manager showing 18,972 K
if i using application continuously it might be caused memory overflow.

Comment: Task Manager is **not** a memory profiler.  Using 1% of available memory isn't going to cause a "memory overflow" any time soon.  Use a real profiler if you are convinced you have a problem.

Comment: how to create  real profiler or suggest me any tools for checking memory overflow , is caused or not.

Comment: The purpose of a garbage collector is to give you the illusion of infinite memory. If the memory usage of your process is negligible and the environment isn't under pressure, a garbage collector that never collects is valid and it's doing its job perfectly.

Comment: you' means that, it is not necessary to call garbage collector in this scenario.

Comment: You should never call it in any scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The Garbage Collector is, by definition, non-deterministic. This means that you can't directly control its behaviours, nor are you intended to do so... Doing so would mean that the .NET runtime was not automatically managing memory for you. You can make some specific calls like `GC.Collect()` but this is **not** recommended. The .NET framework will free up memory for you as needed.

If you're having problems with memory usage, you need to investigate and fix issues in your code. If you have a lot of objects reaching Gen 2, the memory will balloon as it takes longer to collect. Your goal is to either not create new objects, or create short-lived objects that are collected in Gen 0 or 1 (0 is better than 1 here). Evaluate your code and improve to reduce your issues.

On top of all of this, and this is where it gets tricky, the memory reported in Task Manager is **not** the memory USED by your application, but the memory **reserved** for your application by the heuristics of the .NET runtime...

Read this for more information: [.NET Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx)